# Unable to deploy webapp with `mvn tomcat7:deploy`: 401 Unauthorized

Tags: maven, tomcat

I'm trying to auto-deploy my webapps to tomcat using Maven plugin `tomcat7-maven-plugin`. I took the following three steps:

1. Added a new user with deployment rights to tomcat,
2. Introduced the mentioned tomcat user to maven,
3. Edited my project's pom.xml to use the plugin.

For the first step, I added the following lines to the file `conf\tomcat-users.xml` in tomcat's installation directory:

```
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<role rolename="manager-script"/>
<role rolename="manager-jmx"/>
<user username="war-deployer" password="some-password"
    roles="manager-gui,manager-script,manager-jmx" />
```

and then I restarted tomcat.

For the second step, I added the following to the `<servers>` node of `conf\settings.xml` file in `MAVEN_HOME` directory:

```
<server>
    <id>maven-tomcat-war-deployment-server</id>
    <username>war-deployer</username>
    <password>some-password</password>
</server>
```

And finally, to take to third step, I added the following lines to `<plugins>` node of `pom.xml` in my project to use `tomcat7-maven-plugin`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
        <path>/my-project-url-path</path>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I thought everything would go fine, but when typing the command `mvn tomcat7:deploy` my webapp didn't get deployed, nothing was added to tomcat's `webapps` directory, and the following response was sent back from tomcat to the command line:

```
[INFO] tomcatManager status code:401, ReasonPhrase:
[INFO] <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
[INFO] <html>
[INFO]  <head>
[INFO]   <title>401 Unauthorized</title>
[INFO]   <style type="text/css">
[INFO]     <!--
[INFO]     BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;font-size:12px;}
[INFO]     H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;}
[INFO]     PRE, TT {border: 1px dotted #525D76}
[INFO]     A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}
[INFO]     -->
[INFO]   </style>
[INFO]  </head>
[INFO]  <body>
[INFO]    <h1>401 Unauthorized</h1>
[INFO]    <p>
[INFO]     You are not authorized to view this page. If you have not changed
[INFO]     any configuration files, please examine the file
[INFO]     <tt>conf/tomcat-users.xml</tt> in your installation. That
[INFO]     file must contain the credentials to let you use this webapp.
[INFO]    </p>
[INFO]    <p>
[INFO]     For example, to add the <tt>manager-gui</tt> role to a user named
[INFO]     <tt>tomcat</tt> with a password of <tt>s3cret</tt>, add the following to the
[INFO]     config file listed above.
[INFO]    </p>
[INFO] <pre>
[INFO] &lt;role rolename="manager-gui"/&gt;
[INFO] &lt;user username="tomcat" password="s3cret" roles="manager-gui"/&gt;
[INFO] </pre>
[INFO]    <p>
[INFO]     Note that for Tomcat 7 onwards, the roles required to use the manager
[INFO]     application were changed from the single <tt>manager</tt> role to the
[INFO]     following four roles. You will need to assign the role(s) required for
[INFO]     the functionality you wish to access.
[INFO]    </p>
[INFO]     <ul>
[INFO]       <li><tt>manager-gui</tt> - allows access to the HTML GUI and the status
[INFO]           pages</li>
[INFO]       <li><tt>manager-script</tt> - allows access to the text interface and the
[INFO]           status pages</li>
[INFO]       <li><tt>manager-jmx</tt> - allows access to the JMX proxy and the status
[INFO]           pages</li>
[INFO]       <li><tt>manager-status</tt> - allows access to the status pages only</li>
[INFO]     </ul>
[INFO]    <p>
[INFO]     The HTML interface is protected against CSRF but the text and JMX interfaces
[INFO]     are not. To maintain the CSRF protection:
[INFO]    </p>
[INFO]    <ul>
[INFO]     <li>Users with the <tt>manager-gui</tt> role should not be granted either
[INFO]         the <tt>manager-script</tt> or <tt>manager-jmx</tt> roles.</li>
[INFO]     <li>If the text or jmx interfaces are accessed through a browser (e.g. for
[INFO]         testing since these interfaces are intended for tools not humans) then
[INFO]         the browser must be closed afterwards to terminate the session.</li>
[INFO]    </ul>
[INFO]    <p>
[INFO]     For more information - please see the
[INFO]     <a href="/docs/manager-howto.html" rel="noopener noreferrer">Manager App How-To</a>.
[INFO]    </p>
[INFO]  </body>
[INFO] </html>
```

Although no error was reported by maven, and I received a `BUILD SUCCESS` at the end. I've been struggling with the problem for several hours, and searched the Web, but I couldn't find the solution to it. What's wrong with the process that I've followed? Please help me solve it. Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you get a 401 with the default tomcat installation?

Comment: @030 I don't know what you mean by default tomcat installation. But except for the settings related to adding the new user `war-deployer` and its roles, I've changed none of the tomcat's default settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you forgot to link the `<configuration>` for the plugin with the `<server>` definition in settings.xml., and the tomcat7 plugin is trying to deploy as un-authenticated because it has not credentials to try.

Add `<server>maven-tomcat-war-deployment-server</server>` in the configuration section of the plugin:

```
<configuration>
    <server>maven-tomcat-war-deployment-server</server>
    <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
    <path>/my-project-url-path</path>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thank you @GUDO. This solved the problem.